# React-Native, 2023, minCompileSdk (33) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (31) Error

Tags: react-native

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNKBX.png)

I edited the /android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 31 // changed from 33 to 31
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
}
```

But did not solved the problem, now seeking for your answer or suggestion to this problem.